# Can an activity be made to replicate the behaviour of Card view

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

I have an android app where the design of each activity is similar to a card view i.e

The entire activity(Card) can be swiped down to be dismissed.

Few activities(Cards) can have a recycler view within them that are card view.

Before I can start this implementation my question is

Most of the tutorials that I see , card views are used for a recycler view.

Is it a good practise to make an entire activity replicate the behaviour of a card by using card view? Since there are more than 15-20 activities that require this behaviour

Will there be any performance issues?

If not what is the best way to implement this?

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: 15-20 activities  not a good idea you better come up with new approach . Make use of Fragments .

Comment: Is there any example I can refer to?

Comment: If you are looking to implement swipe to dismiss feature for a view, Activity is not for you, there is no way to launch an activity so smoothly to make it feel like swiping cards, you better use RecyclerView with swipeable cards.  Check this one -  https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tinder-swipe-view-example-3eca9b0d4794